# How to compile a simple MLT example in C?

Tags: c, mlt

I am trying to compile an example code from the [MLT Framework website](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/framework/) that shows how consumer/producer work. The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <framework/mlt.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    // Initialise the factory
    if ( mlt_factory_init( NULL ) == 0 )
    {
        // Create the default consumer
        mlt_consumer hello = mlt_factory_consumer( NULL, NULL );

        // Create via the default producer
        mlt_producer world = mlt_factory_producer( NULL, argv[ 1 ] );

        // Connect the producer to the consumer
        mlt_consumer_connect( hello, mlt_producer_service( world ) );

        // Start the consumer
        mlt_consumer_start( hello );

        // Wait for the consumer to terminate
        while( !mlt_consumer_is_stopped( hello ) )
            sleep( 1 );

        // Close the consumer
        mlt_consumer_close( hello );

        // Close the producer
        mlt_producer_close( world );

        // Close the factory
        mlt_factory_close( );
    }
    else
    {
        // Report an error during initialisation
        fprintf( stderr, "Unable to locate factory modules\n" );
    }

    // End of program
    return 0;
}
```

The file name is player.c.
I cannot use make to compile it with `make player` as it does not find include files.

I am using the following command to compile with gcc:

```
 # gcc -I /usr/include/mlt -l libmltcore -o player player.c 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmltcore
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see the linker cannot find the mlt library. OS is Fedora 32 and I have installed mlt-devel and I am sure I have the following libs in /usr/lib64/mlt:

```
libmltavformat.so  libmltlinsys.so      libmltqt.so         libmltvidstab.so
libmltcore.so      libmltmotion_est.so  libmltresample.so   libmltvmfx.so
libmltdecklink.so  libmltnormalize.so   libmltrtaudio.so    libmltvorbis.so
libmltfrei0r.so    libmltoldfilm.so     libmltsdl2.so       libmltxml.so
libmltgtk2.so      libmltopengl.so      libmltsdl.so
libmltjackrack.so  libmltplusgpl.so     libmltsox.so
libmltkdenlive.so  libmltplus.so        libmltvideostab.so
```

What am I doing wrong?

My second question is why does GCC not find the include files and libraries in the first place so that I have to specify them manually?

Comment: "why does GCC not find the include files" - it does; otherwise you wouldn't've gotten to the linking phase. Have you tried `gcc -I /usr/include/mlt -L /usr/lib64/mlt -l libmltcore -o player player.c`?

Comment: No, but there is no file named mlt in the lib directory. Will that work?

Comment: Your post literally says "I am _sure I have_ the following libs in `/usr/lib64/mlt`", and now you suddenly don't have these files?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know L stood for directory. I was looking for a specific file with that name.

Comment: Your command gives this output:  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmltcore
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
gcc -I /usr/include/mlt -l libmltcore -o player player.c`
```

The linker handles things in the order they are listed on the command.  So when the linker encounters `-l libmitcore` there are no unresolved external references so nothing is included so in the end the link step will fail.  Suggest:

```
gcc player.c -o player -I /usr/include/mlt -l libmltcore
```

regarding:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibmltcore
```

if the `libmltcore` is not on one of the 'standard' library directories, it will not be found, UNLESS the command also includes the library path.  Suggest including the following parameter, before the library name:

```
-L /usr/lib64/mlt
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually `gcc player.c -o player -I /usr/include/mlt -l mlt` worked. Surprisingly, I don't have mlt.so in my lib path, rather other lib names starting with libmlt e.g. libmltcore.so, libmltqt.so, and many more